# C# 5.0 in a Nutshell Generics

Tags: c#, generics

It's trying to show me examples of how generics aren't covariant to ensure type safety. Here is the example:

```
class Animal{}
class Bear : Animal {}
class Camel : Animal {}

public class Stack<T> /// a simple stack implementation
{
   int position;
   T[] Data = new T[100];
   public void Push (T obj) { data[position++] = obj;}
   public T Pop() { return data[--position] }
}
Stack<Bear> bears = new Stack<Bear>();
Stack<Animal> animals = bears;     ////COMPILE-TIME ERROR
```

So that is the intent. It also goes on to show how `animals.Push (new Camel());` is not possible either, when I try to run this same code to just see whats going on I get a different set of errors. I imagine it is because I don't understand how to actually RUN the code.

```
namespace C.Fiddle
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Tester.Stack<Bear> bears = new Tester.Stack<Bear>();
         Tester.Stack<Animal> animals = bears;
         animals.Push(new Camel());
      }
   }
}

public class Tester
{
   public class Stack<T>
   {
      int position;
      T[] data = new T[10];
      public void Push(T obj) { data[position++] = obj; }
      public T Pop() { return data[position--]; }
   }

   public class Animal { }
   public class Bear : Animal { }
   public class Camel : Animal { }


   public class ZooCleaner
   {
      private static void Wash<T> (Stack<Animal> animals) where T: Animal {}
   }
}
```

The errors are:

> The type or namespace Bear could not be found (x2)
>   The type or namespace Animal could not be found
>   The type or namespace Camel could not be found
>   Cannot implicity convert type 'Tester.Stack' to Tester.Stack'

The last one is the error I'm looking for. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be defining those classes outside the `Tester` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Tester.Bear`, `Tester.Camel`, and `Tester.Animal` to access those classes because they are nested inside of the `Tester` class.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the point made by John Koerner, your coe module should look like this:

```
namespace C.Fiddle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tester.Stack<Bear> bears = new Tester.Stack<Bear>();
            Tester.Stack<Animal> animals = bears;
            animals.Push(new Camel());
        }
    }

    class Animal { }
    class Bear : Animal { }
    class Camel : Animal { }

    public class Tester
    {
        public class Stack<T>
        {
            int position;
            T[] data = new T[10];
            public void Push(T obj) { data[position++] = obj; }
            public T Pop() { return data[position--]; }
        }

        public class ZooCleaner
        {
            private static void Wash<T>(Stack<Animal> animals) where T : Animal { }
        }
    }
}
```

and you will now have just the one error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'C.Fiddle.Tester.Stack' to
>   'C.Fiddle.Tester.Stack'  c:\users\pieter_2\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  14  44  ConsoleApplication1